# How To Prevent Windows Form Application Looping C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a simple application to convert powerpoint files to PNG files when the application is called by a powershell script. I need the application to open and convert the files then close, however the application opens multiple instances of itself. How can I stop this looping incorrectly? Code example below.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private SynchronizationContext Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public Form1(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hide();           
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Presentation ppt = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(args[0], MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        foreach (Slide slide in ppt.Slides)
        {
            var count = 0;
            slide.Export(@"C:\TestOutputs\slide" + count + ".png", "png", 1920, 1080);
            count++;
        }
        this.Close();
        return;
    }        
}
```

Also here is the powershell script that calls the application.

```
    ### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\AdamSham\Documents\WorkFolder\PowerShellScriptWatcher"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $True
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

            ### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED

$Action = {

$FileName = Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users\AdamSham\Documents\WorkFolder\PowerShellScriptWatcher -recurse -Include @("*.ppt","*.pptx") | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
Set-Location "C:\Users\AdamSham\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PowerpointToPNG\PowerpointToPNG\bin\Debug"
Start-Process ".\PowerpointToPNG.exe" $FileName
Write-Host $FileName

}   

            ### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $Action
while ($True) {Sleep 1}
```

Comment: What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: Also I am very new to programming (3 months or so experience altogether). Have tried Application.Exit etc but visual studio seems to just ignore them.

Comment: It debugs fine when I change args to a hard-coded value and I don't get any errors showing.

Comment: Try to use a console application instead of a Windows Forms application. Just a question: "The application opens multiple instances of itself": do you mean Powerpoint or your application?

Comment: @IgorDamiani I tried a console application and it does the same thing. My application opens multiple instances, as if it just loops through the code repeatedly.

Comment: Can we see also the Powershell script? If the script contains multiple calls to your .exe, it's normal that your application is invoked multiple times. Something prevents your application to close. What's the behavior from Visual Studio?

Comment: Tell us maybe at which line your application becomes unresponsive. 

I mean go through it step by step and check after which step you can't proceed to the next one because previous is still being executed.

Comment: Added the powershell script to the question :) VIsual studio doesn't really give me much information as there are no errors or warnings that I can see. It seems to run everything properly.

Comment: @Zegar The application worked 100% when I was using a "convert" button on a form and manually clicking it. I've only ran into the looping issue when making the process automated with command line arguments etc.

Comment: Where's the loop (other than the `while ($True) {Sleep 1}`) which processes all the files in a folder?

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think there is a loop. It's probably something wrong with the event. Maybe it's being called continuously...

Comment: @ChrisF The only other loop is the foreach in visual studio. The event works fine when I was using it for another application. I have also tried running the application manually from cmd prompt which loops as well. And it loops when debugging lol I'm at a loss

Comment: I was expecting a loop as it sounds like the application is being opened for the next file without waiting for the previous file to finish. Perhaps you need to move your FileSystemWatcher code into the application so you can process the files sequentially.

Comment: Ah, I didn't scroll the code far enough to see the loop in the Powershell ;) It does look like you're not waiting for the current file to finish before processing the next one in the folder. I don't know enough about Powershell to be able to say whether it's fixable there or not, but certainly moving that code into the application will allow you to have more control over the processing of each file.

Comment: @ChrisF It opens up multiple instances even if I am only processing one file though. I have a test powerpoint which is only 1 slide and it still opens up loads of instances for only it.

Comment: So basically, I need 1 instance of my application to run per powerpoint file being processed (so if there are 10 files that need converted, I am fine having 10 instances of my application running at once) but what is happening at the moment is my application will keep opening instances of itself for the exact same file. (20+ instances for one powerpoint file)